# Lineplot by group over time

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, reshape

I am trying to build a line plot showing the change of a certain variable over time by group. My data has values from a single person stored in each row and I am struggling to plot the mean and deviation of the said value over time. Here goes an example of a dataset.

| ID | Group | Value | Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | MDD | 14.2 | 8 |
| 1 | MDD | 15.3 | 9 |
| 2 | NO-MDD | 11.2 | 8 |
| 2 | NO-MDD | 12.3 | 9 |
| 2 | NO-MDD | 12.8 | 5 |
| 3 | NO-MDD | 9.1 | 3 |
| 3 | NO-MDD | 11.3 | 1 |
| 4 | MDD | 10.8 | 5 |
| 4 | MDD | 14.6 | 18 |
| 4 | MDD | 15.3 | 37 |

The time variable stores values from 0 to 37 but not for each participant. It is a large dataset though, so there are enough measurements to calculate SD for each time point. My main problem is the way the data is arranged. I was thinking on reshaping the data but not quite sure if that would be helpful. Here is the expected output drawn by hand, sorry!

[image]

Thank you in advance for any suggestions you can provide!

Answer (score 1):

One option to achieve your desired result with `ggplot2` would be to use multiple `stat_summary` layers to add the mean line and points and the errorbars.

As you example data did not allow to compute a standard deviation by time and group I use some fake random example data:

```r
set.seed(123)

df <- data.frame(
  Time = sample(1:37, 100, replace = TRUE),
  Group = sample(c("MDD", "NO-MDD"), 100, replace = TRUE),
  Value = rnorm(100)
)

df$Value <- df$Value + ifelse(df$Group == "MDD", 2, 0)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(Time, Value, color = Group)) +
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "line") +
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_se, geom = "errorbar") +
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "point")
```

[image]